# How to set time like today, yesterday and date on particular item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, timestamp, message, days

I have ListView, it's showing the messages and time like any chat app. I want to show the time stamp like **Today**,**Yesterday** and also date in ListView. I have set it into the adapter but it's showing in all row but i want just show the starting like yesterday the message all below it and today the messages should show the today's messages.
I stuck in it, please guys help to solve it!!!

I have tried this it's working fine but i want just show in one row item not in all row item

```
public String getSmsTodayYestFromMilli(long msgTimeMillis) {

        Calendar messageTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        messageTime.setTimeInMillis(msgTimeMillis);
        // get Currunt time
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        final String strTimeFormate = "h:mm aa";
        final String strDateFormate = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa";

        if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) == messageTime.get(Calendar.DATE)
                &&
                ((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == messageTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)))
                &&
                ((now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == messageTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                ) {

//            return "today at " + DateFormat.format(strTimeFormate, messageTime);
            return "Today";

        } else if (
                ((now.get(Calendar.DATE) - messageTime.get(Calendar.DATE)) == 1)
                        &&
                        ((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == messageTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)))
                        &&
                        ((now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == messageTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                ) {
//            return "yesterday at " + DateFormat.format(strTimeFormate, messageTime);
            return "Yesterday";
        } else {
            mDay = DateFormat.format(strDateFormate, messageTime) + "";
//            return "date : " + DateFormat.format(strDateFormate, messageTime);
            return DateFormat.format(strDateFormate, messageTime) + "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic problem for every chat app. May be you can start by reading source from this library: [Android Ago library](https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago)

Comment: i have updated my code, it's working fine but the my problem is i want only one time show like today the below all the messages of today same as like whats app!!

Comment: I guess, you want to group messages by Today, yesterday etc ??

Comment: May be you should look at adding section to your recycler view [Sectioned Recycler view] (https://github.com/truizlop/SectionedRecyclerView)

Comment: May be you can also look at expandable recycler view code, [expandablerecyclerview] (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview), and  [Droid con talk about the same] (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this method `getRelativeTimeSpanString` from [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have compare two dates first one is position in getView & another one is previous item (position-1), please try this:

```
       try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            Date date_ = format.parse("Item date time");
            java.text.DateFormat df = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
            vh.chat_time_label_txt.setText(df.format(date_));

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_ = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            vh.top_date_label_txt.setText(dateFormat_.format(date_));
            vh.top_date_label_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (position > 0) {
                XmppChatModel temp = mChatConversationArrayList.get(mChatConversationArrayList.size() - 1);
                Date date__ = format.parse(temp.getTIMESTAMP());
                if (dateFormat_.format(date__)
                    .equals(dateFormat_.format(date_))) {
                    vh.top_date_label_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
      } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           vh.top_date_label_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
```